# how to remove Vue.js in laravel and Add react.js in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, command

you can remove vue.js and add react.js in just single command in laravel

in git bash write a command
$php artisan preset React

Answer (score 0):

set preset

> php artisan preset react

```sh
php artisan preset -h
Description:
  Swap the front-end scaffolding for the application

Usage:
  preset [options] [--] <type>

Arguments:
  type                   The preset type (none, bootstrap, vue, react)

Options:
      --option[=OPTION]  Pass an option to the preset command (multiple values allowed)
  -h, --help             Display this help message
  -q, --quiet            Do not output any message
  -V, --version          Display this application version
      --ansi             Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi          Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction   Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]        The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose   Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

Comment: yup Kamlesh Paul